# Google Script: Searching with a cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add +1 to a value from a customer.

**As example:**

| G8 | K8 |

| Max Mustermann | 140 |

**Goal:**

| G8 | K8 |

| Max Mustermann | 141 |

I have a Script that works fine, but I would like to use the value (Max Mustermann) from a cell (G5).

```
function TextFinden() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
spreadsheet.getRange("G8:G" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Max Mustermann").matchEntireCell(true).findNext().offset(0, 4).activate();

//value +1
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
var value = cell.getValue() * 1;
cell.setValue(value+1);
}
```

**Goal example:**

```
createTextFinder("G5")
```

So, I can write the Name in a cell (G5) and use a Button to add +1 to the Customer.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `As example: G8 | K8 Max Mustermann | 140`, `Goal: G8 | K8 Max Mustermann | 141` and your showing script and `So, I can write the Name in a cell (G5) and use a Button to add +1 to the Customer.`.  Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: Sorry, the final result of my Text was not good.
I edit it now. Maybe now it is better to understand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot still understand your question. What are `As example:` and `Goal:`? And, in your script, it seems that `"G8:G" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()` is used as the range. So, I cannot understand `use the value (Max Mustermann) from a cell (G5).`. And also, I cannot understand `Goal example: createTextFinder("G5")`. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: Thank you, too.
I write the Customer's name in one Cell `G5` and use the Script to find the name in a list `G8:G`. If the customer is found, then go 4 columns to the right `offset(0, 4)` and increase the customer's number +1.
But currently, I have to put the name direct in the script. I would like to take the name from a cell `G5`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed an answer by guessing your expected result. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve a value from cell "G5".
- You want to search the value from cells "G8:G".
- When the value is found, you wan to add `1` to the column "K" of the same row.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const value = sheet.getRange("G5").getDisplayValue();
  const range = sheet.getRange("G8:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(value).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (!range) return;
  const valueRange = range.offset(0, 4);
  valueRange.setValue(valueRange.getValue() + 1);
}
```

#### Note:

- If the value of column "K" is the string value, please modify `valueRange.setValue(valueRange.getValue() + 1)` to `valueRange.setValue(Number(valueRange.getValue()) + 1)`

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Comment: @Sebastian3000 Thank you for replying and testing it. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: One little additional Question: How can I define the Sheet name? Thank you!

Comment: @Sebastian3000 About your additional question of `How can I define the Sheet name?`, in this case, please modify `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` to `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")`.